# Как считать/изменить переменные COLUMNS и LINES из программы?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, терминал

Пробовал считать эти переменные через getenv(), но ничего не вышло, да и сама функция возвращает строку, а не число. Как считать эти переменные из программы используя средства С/С++? Как их изменить, чтобы изменить размер экрана? Какие аналогичные переменные используются в `cmd`?

Comment: Спарсить строки в числа? Как насчет банальных параметров argv?

Comment: @free_ze вопрос в том, как считать и изменить эти переменные из программы - при чем сдесь `argv`? И у вас `getenv` может считать эти переменные прежде чем их спарсить?

Comment: Результат `getenv` можно распарсить. Изменяет значение переменных окружения функция `setenv`. Однако, не факт, что поможет повлиять на размер экрана, если они вычитываются при инициализации окна. Наверняка нужен специальный сискол.

Comment: @free_ze так а вы уверены, что эти переменные можно считать через эту функцию? У меня, например, она возвращает NULL - а у вас?

Comment: Считайте это лирическим отсуплением про переменные окружения) посмотрите в листинг [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733155/how-to-set-the-terminals-size), вероятно, это сможет помочь.

Comment: Ага, вся нужная мне инфа распологается прямо в вопросе - это вреде дополнения для ответа ниже. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Linux размер консоли
# include <sys/ioctl.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <unistd.h>
int main (  int argc  , char *  * argv  ) {
  struct winsize w  ;
  // считать размеры
  ioctl ( STDOUT_FILENO , TIOCGWINSZ  , & w ) ;
  printf (  "lines %d\n"  , w . ws_row  ) ;
  printf (  "columns %d\n"  , w . ws_col  ) ;
  w . ws_row = w . ws_row / 2 ;
  w . ws_col = w . ws_col / 2 ;
  // изменить размеры
  ioctl ( STDOUT_FILENO , TIOCSWINSZ  , & w ) ;
  // считать размеры
  ioctl ( STDOUT_FILENO , TIOCGWINSZ  , & w ) ;
  printf (  "lines %d\n"  , w . ws_row  ) ;
  printf (  "columns %d\n"  , w . ws_col  ) ;
  return 0  ; }
```

Comment: отлично - то что нужно, но вопрос по поводу измения этих переменных остается открытым

Comment: изменить размер консоли можно, но с окном ещё надо повозится

Comment: мне нужно только изменить размер консоли

Comment: но у меня ничего не меняется при использовании этого кода. Всмысле цифры меняются, но размер остается темже

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, изменением размера окна занимается сам эмулятор терминала (вообще-то это X-window (т.е. графическая) программа). У каждой свой интерфейс. В принципе, можно попробовать посмотреть, как это реализовать через диспетчер окон, например, эмулируя действия пользователя с мышью. Т.е. тут надо смотреть на графический интерфейс и задавать соответствующие вопросы.